# Copy DIV content to another page - PHP

Tags: php, html, onclick, copy

I want to copy the content of a div (.boxes) to another page (drills.php) when I click on one of them.
Here is my HTML

```
   <div class="boxes le8">
       <div class="img" style="background-image:url(http://charlesfstcyr.890m.com/coaching/img/drills/le8.png)"></div>
       <h1>Le 8</h1>
       <p class="date">Octobre 2016 - Dany Dubé</p>
       <div style="display:none">
           <p class="description">Patinage en 8 autour des cônes.</p>
           <p class="enseignement">Virage brusques, Contrôle de rondelle, Croisement en sortie de virage.</p>
           <p class="variantes">Départ au sifflet pour 10 virages le plus rapidement possible, Rapprocher les cônes jusqu’à une distance de 1 bâton entre les cônes,Passes à l’entraineur en sortie de virage.</p>
           <video src="img/drillsVid/Le8.mp4" autoplay controls muted loop></video>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="boxes chandelle">
       <div class="img" style="background-image:url(http://charlesfstcyr.890m.com/coaching/img/drills/chandelle.png)"></div>
       <h1>La Chandelle</h1>
       <p class="date">Octobre 2016 - Dany Dubé</p>
       <div style="display:none">
           <p class="description">Départ au centre du cercle de mise-en-jeu avec une rondelle. Contourner le premier cône et remonter vers le cône en haut de zone pour effectuer un virage brusque. Revenir contourner le troisième cône et par la suite revenir au point d’origine par l’extérieur des cônes en laissant la rondelle à son point d’origine avant de récupérer une rondelle de l’autre côté. Effectuer le trajet inverse avec la deuxième rondelle.</p>
           <p class="enseignement">Croisement lors des virages, </p>
           <p class="enseignement">Changement de direction rapide,   </p>
           <p class="enseignement">Protection de rondelle.</p>
           <p class="variantes">Passe à l’entraineur situé sur la ligne bleu, </p>
           <p class="variantes">Lancer au but(2 lancers), </p>
           <p class="variantes">Tour complet de chacun des cônes dans la première portion du parcours.</p>
           <video src="img/drillsVid/chandelle.mp4" autoplay controls muted loop></video>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="boxes pcoin">
       <div class="img" style="background-image:url(http://charlesfstcyr.890m.com/coaching/img/drills/pcoin.png)"></div>
       <h1>Le Petit Coin</h1>
       <p class="date">Octobre 2016 - Dany Dubé</p>
       <div style="display:none">
           <p class="description">Départ sur le point de mise-en-jeu en poussant la rondelle dans le coin. Le joueur récupère la rondelle et se dirige le long de la bande pour passer entre le cône et le but. Patiner entre le cône pour aller contourner le second cône. Se diriger au filet pour prendre un lancer.</p>
           <p class="enseignement">Récupération de rondelle, </p>
           <p class="enseignement">Récupération de rondelle, </p>
           <p class="enseignement">Récupération de rondelle</p>
           <p class="variantes">Remonter vers le haut de la zone au départ pour effectuer le trajet en sens inverse, </p>
           <p class="variantes">Passe à l’entraineur situé sur le haut du cercle de mise-en-jeu.</p>
           <video src="img/drillsVid/pcoin.mp4" autoplay controls muted loop></video>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="boxes gcoin">
       <div class="img" style="background-image:url(http://charlesfstcyr.890m.com/coaching/img/drills/gcoin.png)"></div>
       <h1>Le Grand Coin</h1>
       <p class="date">Octobre 2016 - Dany Dubé</p>
       <div style="display:none">
           <p class="description">Départ sur le point de mise-en-jeu, le joueur lance la rondelle dans le coin. Le joueur la récupère, se dirige le long de la bande pour remonter entre le cône et le but. Il se dirige ensuite vers la gauche pour contourner les deux autres cônes de l’extérieur. Il redescend en fond de zone pour contourner le cône à partir de la droite et revenir devant le filet pour prendre un lancer.</p>
           <p class="enseignement">Récupération de rondelle, </p>
           <p class="enseignement">Virages brusques, </p>
           <p class="enseignement">Lancer en espace restreint</p>
           <p class="variantes">Passe à un joueur 2 devant le filet pour lancer sur réception, </p>
           <p class="variantes">Tour complet de chacun des cônes</p>
           <video src="img/drillsVid/gcoin.mp4" autoplay controls muted loop></video>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="boxes fleur">
       <div class="img" style="background-image:url(http://charlesfstcyr.890m.com/coaching/img/drills/fleur.png)"></div>
       <h1>La Fleur</h1>
       <p class="date">Octobre 2016 - Dany Dubé</p>
       <div style="display:none">
           <p class="description">Départ au centre. Contourner chacun des cônes en revenant toujours au point de mis-en-jeu. Après le 4ième cône, repasser au point de mise-en-jeu et se diriger au filet pour un lancer. Lors des diagonales, s’assurer de croiser le centre pour contourner les cônes autant du revers que du coup droit.</p>
           <p class="enseignement">Virages brusques, </p>
           <p class="enseignement">Protection de rondelle, </p>
           <p class="enseignement">Croisement en sortie de virage.</p>
           <p class="variantes">Course avec des joueurs dans chacun des cercles.</p>
           <video src="img/drillsVid/fleur.mp4" autoplay controls muted loop></video>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="boxes model final">
       <div class="img" style="background-image:url(../img/drills/.png)"></div>
       <h1>Nom</h1>
       <p class="date">Date - Auteur</p>
       <div style="display:none">
           <p class="description">Description</p>
           <p class="enseignement">Item1 /\n/ Item2 /\n/ Item3</p>
           <p class="variantes">Item1 /\n/ Item2 /\n/ Item3</p>
           <video src="img/drillsVid/.mp4" autoplay controls muted loop></video>
       </div>
   </div>
```

I have done something similar with Javascript to copy it in a DIV but I really want to copy it on another page.

For now, [here's the result](http://charlesfstcyr.890m.com/coaching/drill.html) with the Javascript

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean by saying "I want to copy the content of the div to another page when it was clicked". On your site when I click the div it opens a big popup with video.

Comment: Yes, but I want to open those element into an other page. The elements are in the box it's just hidden